# Creating a new column based on selecting by multiple conditions between two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that contain (some) common columns (A,B,C), but are ordered differently and have different values for C.

I'd like to replace the 'C' values in first dataframe with those from the second.

I can create a toy example like this:

```
A = [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 ]
B = [ 'x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'x' ]
C = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i' ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame( { 'A' : A,
                      'B' : B,
                      'C' : C } )

A.reverse()
B.reverse()
C = [ c.upper() for c in reversed(C) ]

df2 = pd.DataFrame( { 'A' : A,
                      'B' : B,
                      'C' : C } )
```

I'd like to update df1 so that it looks like this - i.e. it has the 'C' values from df2:

```
A = [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 ]
B = [ 'x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'x' ]
C = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' ]
```

I've tried:

```
df1['C'] =  df2[ (df2['A'] == df1['A']) & (df2['B'] == df1['B']) ]['C']
```

but that doesn't work because, I think, the order of A and B are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
merge_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A', 'B'])
df1['C'] = merge_df['C_y']
```

I think your toy code has a problem in [ c.upper() for c in C.reverse() ].
C.reverse() return None.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy, because duplicates in columns `A` and `B` (`3,x`).
So I create new columns `D` by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and then use 
[`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), last remove unnecessary columns:

```
df1['D'] = df1.groupby(['A','B']).C.cumcount()
df2['D'] = df2.groupby(['A','B']).C.cumcount(ascending=False)

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A','B','D'], how='right', suffixes=('_',''))
df3 = df3.drop(['C_', 'D'], axis=1)
print (df3)
   A  B  C
0  1  x  A
1  1  y  B
2  1  z  C
3  2  x  D
4  2  y  E
5  2  y  F
6  3  x  G
7  3  x  H
8  3  x  I
```